# Why are the bounds of type parameters ignored when using existential types in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-inference, type-parameter, bounded-types

What I mean is this:

```
scala> class Bounded[T <: String](val t: T)
defined class Bounded

scala> val b: Bounded[_] = new Bounded("some string")
b: Bounded[_] = Bounded@2b0a141e

scala> b.t
res0: Any = some string
```

Why does res0 have type Any and not String? It sure could know that b.t is at least a String. Writing

```
val b: Bounded[_ <: String] = new Bounded("some string")
```

works, but it is redundant with respect to the declaration of the class itself.

Comment: Why not just `val b = new Bounded("some string")`? b is inferred as Bounded[String].

Comment: Isn't it exactly like asking why `val o: Any = "some string"` has type of Any instead of String?

Comment: @IttayD Yes, you could omit the type annotation. My actual problem was in a method argument, where you cannot omit it. Besides, I don't agree with your second comment: when I write `b.t`, I'm getting back an object of a type T <: String, so at least a String, as guaranteed by the definition of Bounded. Therefore, I was hoping that res0 would have type String and not any, without using a type annotation like in your example.

Comment: You should have shown the method problem, then. I imagine it goes like `def m[T](x: T) = new Bounded(x)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I have edited the question title. You are not using dependent types, which Scala doesn't have anyway, but *existential* types. Second, you are not inferring anything, you are explicitly declaring the type.

Now, if you did write `Bounded[Any]`, Scala wouldn't let you. However, one of the uses of existential types is to deal with situations where the type parameter is completely unknown -- such as Java raw types, where.

So my guess is that making an exception in a situation that seems obvious enough will break some other situation where existential type is the only way to deal with something.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Daniel. Now, I don't insist on using "existential types", I'd just like to access b.t passed from a Bounded object with unknown parametrization, and know that it's a String and not Any. Is the only solution to write the type bound as in `val b: Bounded[_ <: String] = new Bounded("some string")`? And have to manually change it everywhere I use Bounded, if some day the type bound in the original declaration of Bounded becomes less restrictive? Argh, raw types...

Comment: @JPP If you want to know how to avoid writting the boundaries everywhere, please ask it on another question. No one would click on _this_ question to look up for that answer! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There was a lengthy discussion about this topic recently on the mailing list, [Type Boundary "Stickyness" on Wildcards](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8018).

It wasn't conclusive, other than to agree that existential types, such as `Bounded[_]` (a shorthand for `Bounded[$1] forSome { type $1 }`), don't lend themselves to intuition.

@extempore did find one upside to the discussion :)

> On the plus side I'm finally reading
>   the spec cover to cover. I had no idea
>   the complete lyrics to "yellow
>   submarine" were in the specification!
>   Yet I have to admit, in context it was
>   hard to see any other way that section
>   could have been written.

Comment: "I had no idea the complete lyrics to "yellow submarine" were in the specification!" ... Where? Which pages? :-P