# Type bound error when creating a tuple in scala

Tags: scala, existential-type

Say I have a type

```
trait Mode[T]
trait MyType[T, M <: Mode[T]]
```

This compiles

```
val t: MyType[_, _] = ???
t
```

But not this one

```
val t: MyType[_, _] = ???
"some_string" -> t
```

Error says something like `type arguments [_$0,_$1] do not conform to trait MyType's type parameter bounds`

So my question is that why this does not compile on tuple creation?

Comment: By the way, if you specify types for tuple explicitly this compiles: `Tuple2[String, MyType[_, _]]("some_string", t)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323140/why-are-the-bounds-of-type-parameters-ignored-when-using-existential-types-in-sc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually both `t` and `"some string" -> t` will break at runtime with the same issue:

```
import scala.language.existentials
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

type SubMode[T] = M forSome { type M <: Mode[T] }

val t: MyType[_, _] = new MyType[String, SubMode[String]] {}
// t: MyType[_, _] = $anon$1@596afb2f

"some string" -> t
// error: type arguments [_$1,_$2] do not conform to trait MyType's type parameter bounds [T,M <: Mode[T]]

reify(t)
// error: type arguments [_$1,_$2] do not conform to trait MyType's type parameter bounds [T,M <: Mode[T]]

reify("some string" -> t)
// error: type arguments [_$1,_$2] do not conform to trait MyType's type parameter bounds [T,M <: Mode[T]]
```

In fact, the issue at compile-time is not specific to Tuples.  For example:

```
List(t)
// error: type arguments [_$1,_$2] do not conform to trait MyType's type parameter bounds [T,M <: Mode[T]]
```

My guess is that while the definition of `t` alone does not trigger a compilation error, an additional "touch" on `t` might.  It'll all work fine if you let the compiler infer the proper type:

```
val t2 = new MyType[String, SubMode[String]] {}
t2: MyType[String,SubMode[String]] = $anon$1@19d53ab4

"some string" -> t2
// res1: (String, MyType[String,SubMode[String]]) = (some string,$anon$1@19d53ab4)

List(t2)
// res2: List[MyType[String,SubMode[String]]] = List($anon$1@19d53ab4)
```

Comment: "any additional "touch" on t does" It's not so easy. `trait Mode[T]`
  `trait MyType[T1, M1 <: Mode[T1]] {
    def foo: Any
  }`  `val t: MyType[_, _] = ???` `t.foo` compiles.

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin, thanks for the example.  I've softened the said clause.